# Loading own Composer Stack

Tags: plugin, composer

I am working on Joomla 3.9.24
I want to globally load my own composer Stack which resides in JPATH_ROOT/vendor

I tried it with a plugin that just includes the autoload and a file for starting some classes but this doesn't work. I always get the message that functions are not valid.

I assume the autoloader from Joomla is overwriting the autoloader from composer.

Is there a way, so I can access all the Composer libraries with the inclusion of a plugin?

Background:
The Joomla is modified, and we integrate some 3rd party software.

Edit Code:

```
class plgSystemComposer extends JPlugin
{
    function onAfterInitialise()
    {

            require_once('/var/www/<path>/htdocs/vendor/autoload.php');
    }
}
```

Error Message: 0 Call to a member function input() on null´

input() is from Illuminate\Http;

The code I use works outside of Joomla, also the plugin works because I can do die('test') and the page only shows "test" afterwards.

So my assumption is still that the Joomla autoloader doesn't let composer load the files. (otherwise I should get different errors)

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support.  If you manage to resolve your own question, please post how you did it as an educational answer.

Comment: I assume you are trying something like this https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16815/how-to-add-a-composer-package-without-modifying-the-core-composer-json-file/18914#18914

Comment: Some code or errors would be helpful too.

Comment: Yes I do, the problem is that the autoloader is not working.
I can add code, but it will not help because the only error I get is that the first function I call is not valid (as I described).
This is why I assume it is a problem with the autoloader

Comment: 1. autoloaders don't overwrite one another. 2. there is something wrong with the way you have set up your code which is difficult to guess without providing more detail.  Please add your plugin code to your original question.

Comment: Try putting the following after your require_once statement.  $request = \Illuminate\Http\Request::capture(); echo $request->fullUrl(); die();